# Encode Raw to Video

Tags: video, wav

I am looking for a way of hiding my files into a video file

I can use GoldWave to hide a rar File into a Wav sound clip by just importing it as a Raw Snd format and then converting it to Wav and it working perfect - the sound is just noise but that is what i wanted -

but i can't do it in video file

the idea is to hide the file in encoding of video file so it plays like normal video file but the content is my file

I don't want to merge them using copy/b and these stuff

Simply i want to add the header of any file format to my file so it can be played by any media player